# Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Tags: c#

I am creating a game in unity but im getting the error:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'.

Does anyone know the awnser?

```
public Text text;

int max;
int min;
int guess;

void Start () {

    text.text = ("Pick a number in your head between " + min);
    text.text =  + max;
    text.text = (" , but dont tell me!");

    max = 1000;
    min = 1;
    guess = 500;

}
```

Comment: it's here `text.text =  + max`. You are assigning int to string

Comment: Try `text.text += ...` for your second and third lines

Comment: To solve debugging problems like these, strike other steps first. 1. **Google** the error. That will help. 2. Take a look at the **error description**. 3. Get as much info as you can before posting. Which line does this occur in?

Comment: that fixed it lol, thanks ta.seot.is

Comment: @devRicher i have googled first!

Comment: Try changing your first line to `text.text = ($"Pick a number in your head between {min} and {max}, but don't tell me!");`. That should put it all in one line. @FluffyMe

Comment: @devRicher If the question is related to the unity framework, I don't know whether C# 6.0 is available (last time I checked - which was admittedly a couple of years ago, the Unity team had not evolved beyond .NET 3.5).   But `string.Format` would certainly be an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public Text text;

int max;
int min;
int guess;

void Start () {
    max = 1000;
    min = 1;
    guess = 500;

    text.text = ("Pick a number in your head between " + min.ToString());
    text.text += max.ToString();
    text.text += (" , but dont tell me!");
}
```

But there is a better and more optimized way to concatenate strings, try this:

```
public Text text;

int max;
int min;
int guess;

void Start () {
    max = 1000;
    min = 1;
    guess = 500;

    text.text = string.Format("Pick a number in your head between {0} and {1}, but dont tell me!", min.ToString(), max.ToString());
}
```